# Problem with recursively downloading files from mounted cd disc

Tags: linux, sftp

I try to recursively download remote folder (cd disc is mounted to this folder) but it fails, probably due to non-ascii file names:

```
> sftp mati@mati
mati@192.168.1.3's password:
Connected to mati@mati.

sftp> cd "/run/media/mati/Marcin Zielinski/"
sftp> ls -l
dr-x------    1 mati     mati         2048 Aug 23  2017 K1 - BÓG NIE DAJE TANDETY, ALE TO, CO NAJLEPSZE
(...)

sftp> get -r "K1 - BÓG NIE DAJE TANDETY, ALE TO, CO NAJLEPSZE"
Fetching /run/media/mati/Marcin Zielinski/K1 - BÓG NIE DAJE TANDETY, ALE TO, CO NAJLEPSZE/ to K1 - BÓG NIE DAJE TANDETY, ALE TO, CO NAJLEPSZE
Retrieving /run/media/mati/Marcin Zielinski/K1 - BÓG NIE DAJE TANDETY, ALE TO, CO NAJLEPSZE
Couldn't open local file "K1 - B\303\223G NIE DAJE TANDETY, ALE TO, CO NAJLEPSZE/1 - K1-B\303\263g nie daje tandety, ale to co najlepsze.mp3" for writing: Permission denied
Download of file /run/media/mati/Marcin Zielinski/K1 - B\303\223G NIE DAJE TANDETY, ALE TO, CO NAJLEPSZE/1 - K1-B\303\263g nie daje tandety, ale to co najlepsze.mp3 to K1 - B\303\223G NIE DAJE TANDETY, ALE TO, CO NAJLEPSZE/1 - K1-B\303\263g nie daje tandety, ale to co najlepsze.mp3 failed
(...)
```

I see that non-ascii letters are translated, for example `Ó` is `\303\223` in the error message and probably that's why it fails (UPDATE: this is not the reason). **How can I download whole folder recursively with sftp?**

When I download files using `folder/*` notation, everything works fine (file names are not translated):

```
sftp> get -r "K1 - BÓG NIE DAJE TANDETY, ALE TO, CO NAJLEPSZE"/*
Fetching /run/media/mati/Marcin Zielinski/K1 - BÓG NIE DAJE TANDETY, ALE TO, CO NAJLEPSZE/1 - K1-Bóg nie daje tandety, ale to co najlepsze.mp3 to 1 - K1-Bóg nie daje tandety, ale to co najlepsze.mp3
/run/media/mati/Marcin Zielinski/K1 - BÓG NIE DAJE TANDETY, ALE TO, CO NAJLEPSZE/1 - K1-Bóg nie daje tandety, ale to co najlepsze.mp3                                      100% 2395KB  97.7MB/s   00:00
Fetching /run/media/mati/Marcin Zielinski/K1 - BÓG NIE DAJE TANDETY, ALE TO, CO NAJLEPSZE/2 - K1-Bóg nie daje tandety, ale to co najlepsze.mp3 to 2 - K1-Bóg nie daje tandety, ale to co najlepsze.mp3
/run/media/mati/Marcin Zielinski/K1 - BÓG NIE DAJE TANDETY, ALE TO, CO NAJLEPSZE/2 - K1-Bóg nie daje tandety, ale to co najlepsze.mp3                                      100% 4585KB 107.6MB/s   00:00
(...)
```

Both local and remote host are running Manjaro x64.

Comment: The actual error is permission denied while trying to create the local file. Do you have write permission on the local directory where these files would be saved?

Comment: Yes, I do have permissions to write files in local dir. It downloads the files properly when I use `get -r folder/*` instead of `get -r folder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with directories permissions on remote server. They lack the "write" permission, so I cannot save any files in them while downloading. I copied whole directory to `/tmp/cd_disc`, changed all permissions with: `chmod -R u+w /tmp/cd_disc` and then I could download `/tmp/cd_disc` through sftp without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Both the sftp client and the sftp server need to be configured for UTF8 encoding.

Once this is done, it should work properly.